# How to create a dynamic Link to attribute in React-Router 2.5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

(Disclaimer: I am new to React and React-Router, so this may be obvious to someone with more familiarity)

I am creating a simple project with React-Router 2.5.2 with ES6 and I have a working solution but it feels like it may not be the "React Router way". I have this Route:

```
<Route path="lists/:listId" component={List}/>
```

and elsewhere I have a Link:

```
<Link to={`/lists/${props.list._id}`}>{props.list.name}</Link>
```

Is this the preferred way to compose a "to" attribute that passes dynamic content? Or am I fundamentally misunderstanding React Router?

Comment: Well, yes. If you need more control over location you can pass [LocationDescriptor](https://github.com/ReactJSTraining/history/blob/master/docs/Glossary.md#locationdescriptor) instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are doing it right! :)

As you can see in the docs, this is the correct way to pass the `to` prop:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/v2.5.2/docs/API.md#link

In previous React Router versions, there was a prop called `params`, where you would pass all your route params.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v0.13.6/doc/03%20Components/Link.md#params

But I think the React Router team decided to keep things simple, so you decide how you will build your routes. Also, using ES6 templates fit very well with that.

Comment: Url not working : https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/0.13.x/doc/03%20Components/Link.md#params

Comment: Just updated the answer with the correct link (https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v0.13.6/doc/03%20Components/Link.md#params) @Chandresh

Answer (score 20):

In the API-documentation of `react-router` it is done in the exact same way:

```
// change the activeClassName
<Link to={`/users/${user.id}`} activeClassName="current">{user.name}</Link>
```

Reference: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#link